# Huge amount of temp files causing server to crash. How to store virt files in a different location in jasper report server

Tags: tomcat, jasperserver

I'm using jasper report server 6.2.0 and we have some huge reports generating up to 50k, 60k pages. The first 300 pages will stored in memory and rest of those pages would be generated as virt files ( temp) in /opt/jasper-report-server/apache-tomcat/temp.

Is jasper expected to delete these temp/virt files by itself once the report is generated.

I want to store this virt files in a different location, since opt mount has only 15GB and its fills up rather quickly causing jasper to shutdown.

I tried setting the below variable in tomcat setenv.sh which has better storage but no luck.

```
     JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/xyz/temp/
```

Comment: Crash how? Large numbers of files in a directory don't crash applications. Are you perhaps leaking file descriptors?

Answer (score 1):

In **applicationContext.xml** you should find the **fileVirtualizerFactory** bean and the **directory** property. Try to set here your path.

Comment: should be something like `<bean id="fileVirtualizerFactory" ... <property name="directory" value="${java.io.tmpdir}">`

Comment: see also: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/virtualizers-jasperreports